# Can I use hard surface protectant to prevent algal growth on my aquarium front glass? Is there something else that will prevent them sticking?

Tags: aquarium

Siliconizing glass makes it non-sticky.  Does that or something else prevent algae from sticking to glass so I won't have to scrape the front pane all the time?
I want to treat the tank before setup.

Comment: Don't treat the tank. Get [fish, snails or shrimp that eat the algae](https://nualgiaquarium.com/best-algae-eaters-freshwater-aquarium/)! See [this site](https://www.fishkeepingworld.com/13-must-have-algae-eaters-for-your-aquarium/) too. When I had an aquarium, I had plecos of various species do the vacuuming. [Corys](https://www.thesprucepets.com/pepper-cory-1380839) are good for cleaning the tank bottom, too.

Comment: Nerite snails are awesome at keeping glass clean, and they don't reproduce in fresh water so no risk of your tank being overrun! Its also super fun to watch them scrape the glass with their little mouth/radula.